# Don't autocrop video when having different dimensions of videos

Tags: rendering, video

Lets say I want to have an video with 1000x1000px dimensions.

My source video is FullHD (1920x1080) and if I paste it into my Video Editing Screen it gets automatically cropped to fit the desired dimensions.

[image: Original Video]
[image: Cropped Video in Blender]

What I basically want is to have the video at its max height cropped down but therefore only displaying the 1000x1000 square from the original video, like so:

[image]

How would I do this?

Comment: Are you adding it to the VSE? This will always distort your images to fit the current dimensions/aspect ratio.

Comment: How else would I edit videos in Blender? @3pointedit

Answer (score 3):

First set your render settings Resolution to X:1000 px and Y:1000 px. In Video Sequence Editor right click on the name of the video that you are editing with the ending .001 (or similar). Open the options window with N and select Crop option and crop away the top, bottom, left and right to get the size that you need. To constantly see what you are doing the option at the bottom Use Backdrop is also good to be turned on.

[image: Crop Video Sequence]

Answer (score 0):

In the VSE you can use the Crop function of the Strip properties. This will return the strip to its original dimensions, then you use the Offset function to slide it around to your liking. But you cannot scale the original media down, you can only resize the part visible in the preview window (a crop).

Alternitively you could import the image as a 3D plane using Import Image as Plane addon and shoot it in the 3D view in its own scene. Then use a scene strip in the editing VSE scene. This would allow you to reframe and scale the image more easily at full quality. However the render time will be longer. You can sort of use OpenGL render to ease this render time.

Finally you could use the compositor to import and scale/translate the image and render out from there but audio handling becomes an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my fast method after installing the [VSE_Transform_Tools addon](https://github.com/doakey3/VSE_Transform_Tools). Otherwise, I'd go with [the answer given by Matej Kovačič](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/108642/31751)

1. Press C to bring up the Crop tool
2. Press Shift+C to autocrop the canvas to the cropped footage

[image]

Comment: Ouhhhh that looks nice. Thanks for adding it!